# Office 2010 muti region OEM?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, oem, licensing

Buying a laptop from Germany, we use OEM licensing from the US (all above board, just the OEM loophole)

Are OEM licenses multi-region or will we have to buy a specific office product for use in Germany?

Thanks
j

Comment: You can purchase any version of Microsoft's product from any region and use it in any region.

Comment: OK thanks. I did a little research into this and found this - 

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/activate-a-region-specific-version-of-microsoft-office-home-and-student-2010-HA010354226.aspx

Hence I then had to ask the question if other versions were country/region specific.

Comment: Yes;  Home and Student is an exception to my statement.  That is because the discounted license is not offered in every region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OEM Licenses are indeed multi-region.  Once you have purchased a license for the software, you can install it on any region/language version you like.

Tne only exception to this are home and student versions of some ms software can be region locked (see comment above) for the reason stated by Ramhound (discounted licenses are not available in every region where the software is sold).

Comment: Thanks - we found that although Office is not region specific, Windows is. If we buy Windows OEM for example from Canada, we cannot install and use it in Europe. Well thats what MS told me anyway.